# Update base properties - ASP.NET MVC- c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a model

```
base.Name = instance.Name;
base.SSN = instance.SSN;
base.DateModified = DateTime.Now
base.ClienType = instance.ClientType;
```

If I add more properties to my base then i have to update my model to update the properties. Is there an easier way to update the base.properties instead of listing each of them and then updating the same? 
Yes i know i am being lazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are doing this, but you might want to take a look at [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) - if your properties are the same on both side you can get it to automatically map one to the other without doing any real setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Automapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) to automatically map where there is a naming convention.

Also beware that things the following would not map as one has one less t

```
base.ClienType = instance.ClientType;
```